# How to replace all occurrences of \ only if they are not followed by n?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Seems to be relatively simple task that gets me stuck in one PHP application. I have a string which has a bunch of `\n` in it. Those are fine and need to stay there. However, there are also single occurrences of the character `\` and those I need to replace or remove, let's just say with empty character without removing the ones that are followed by `n`.

The best I came up with was to first replace all `\n` with something else, some weird character, then replace the remaining `\` with empty space and then convert back the weird character to `\n`. However, that seems to be a waste of time and resources, besides, nothing guarantees me that I'll find weird enough character that will never be encountered in the rest of the string...

Any tips?

Comment: what regex have you tried?

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace('~\\\\(?!n)~', '', $s)`?

Comment: Why do you need regex for that? Do you have `\n` or `\\n`? The \ in `\n` is **not** a real \. Check this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea7362ab63707e8e615a2090775b8f28ff94809b

Comment: I can't really figure out how to do this with regular expression as this is not my most fluent language. Wiktor, would you mind explaining yours?

Comment: I am not sure what you really need. I suggested the preg_replace above that just removes all occurrences of a backslash that is not followed with `n`.

Comment: i think he is asking for an explanation of what that regex is doing

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need but I'm not sure why you used four times `\\` instead of just two?

Comment: Backslashes are eaten everywhere! Its kind a hart to explain it here, not impossible :)!  PHP eats them, MYSQL eats them.

Comment: `used four times instead of just two`, thats because any instance that handles the string may remove (eats) one backshlash from it. Have you ever tryed do get rwos from an table with `field like '%\%'`, try it and you will get it ;)

Comment: @mmvsbg: I posted the answer then with the necessary explanations and a code demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
$s = preg_replace('~\\\\(?!n)~', '', $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/RC0A6i):

```
$s = '\\n \\t \\';
$s = preg_replace('~\\\\(?!n)~', '', $s);
echo $s; // => \n t
```

We need 4 backslashes to pass 2 literal backslashes to the regex engine to match 1 literal backslash in the input string. The `(?!n)` is a *negative lookahead* that fails all matches of a backslash that is immediately followed with `n`.

Comment: Also, see [PHP string literals reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php): *To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (``\``).* - both in single- and double-quoted string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a negative lookahead assertion:

```
\\(?!n)
```

The `\\` looks for the backslash, the `(?!n)` asserts that the next character is not an n, but does not match the character.

To use this in PHP:

```
$text = 'foo\nbar\nb\az\n';
$newtext = preg_replace('/\\\\(?!n)/', '', $text);
```

Details here: https://regex101.com/r/F2qhAP/1

Comment: this regex seems much simpler than other answers +1 for negative lookahead assertion